# Delete method in binary search tree: Original node not being deleted

Tags: ruby

I am making a delete method in a binary search tree but when I find the node to be deleted I cannot delete it. I have looked at many different things and cannot figure it out for myself. I have included the class that builds the nodes and the class that builds the tree (build_tree). The delete method is in the Tree class...

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :left, :right

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end

end

def build_tree(array)
  root_value = array[0]
  if array.length == 0
    return
  elsif array.length == 1 
    root = Node.new(array)
  elsif array.length == 2
    if array[1] > root_value
      root = Node.new(root_value)
      root.right = Node.new(array[1])
    else
      root = Node.new(root_value)
      root.left = Node.new(array[1])
    end  
  else
    left_side = []
    right_side = []

    for i in 0...array.length
      if array[i] < root_value
        left_side << array[i]
      elsif array[i] > root_value
        right_side << array[i]
      end
    end

  root = Node.new(root_value)
  root.left = build_tree(left_side)
  root.right = build_tree(right_side)

  end
  root

end

class Tree

  def initialize(array)
    @root = build_tree(array)
  end

  def inorder(root=@root)
    if root
      inorder(root.left)
      puts(root.data)
      inorder(root.right)
    end
  end

  #!!!
  def delete(root=@root, value)
    if root.data == nil
      return root
    elsif root.data < value
      delete(root.right, value)
    elsif root.data > value
      delete(root.left, value)
    else
     # no child node
      if root.right == nil && root.left == nil
        #v Something must be wrong with this here v
        root = nil

      end
    end
    root
  end

end

test_array = [10,7,14,20,1,5,8]

new_tree = Tree.new(test_array)

new_tree.delete(20)

new_tree.inorder()

#prints [1,5,7,8,10,14,20]
```

The node with value 20 is still in the tree. How do I fix this so it gets deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `root = nil` just nils the local reference. It doesn't nil the parent's `right` or `left` value, which is what you'd want to actually drop the node from the tree.

One way to work this might be to pass a block which gets invoked if the child doesn't have any child nodes. This captures the desired operation, and lets the recursed method call invoke it if it determines that the deletion should in fact occur.

```
  def delete(root=@root, value, &block)
    return root if root.data.nil?

    if root.data < value
      delete(root.right, value) { root.right = nil }
    elsif root.data > value
      delete(root.left, value) { root.left = nil }
    elsif root.right.nil? && root.left.nil?
      yield if block_given?
    end

    root
  end
```

(Additionally: there is a potential bug here. The first two conditions don't check if `root.right` or `root.left` are nil, and will attempt to recurse into them regardless. You may want to add additional guards for that possibility.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't really understand what the block would say in order to delete the node. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: The block is the part in curly braces after the delete() invocations. It's effectively a callback to be optionally run. In my example, it runs `root.right = nil` or `root.left = nil`.

Comment: Could you please explain the yield if block_given?

Comment: `yield` invokes whichever block was passed to the method you're calling. `block_given?` asserts that a block was passed. If you attempt to yield without a passed block, you'll have an exception thrown.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding a parent node attribute to my node class and deleted the nodes that way. I will try this method too. Thanks again